# Cannot boot from Windows 7 DVD after nuking with DBAN

Tags: windows-7, dban

i have a Lenovo 3000 series. I've ‘nuked it’ with DBAN and the disk is clean no partition. The problem now is that i cant install windowd 7. have tried windows 7 dvd, have tried windows 7 iso as well,both of them with no luck. the black screen writes OS not found.

specification of computer.

- 2GB ram
- hitachi HDD 250GB
- core duo 1.70 Ghz

Please help, new at this,still learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the `OS Not Found` message, then you aren't booting from the CD/DVD and will likely need to enable this option in the BIOS.

**These instructions are Lenovo specific, but should be translatable by using visual cues**

To Enable booting from different devices in the BIOS:

- As you start up the computer tap the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key until you see the **Boot Interupt Menu**. One of these options should allow you to enter the System Setup (or BIOS). Most Lenovo machines use a fairly similar style of BIOS, however I am unfamiliar with the exact model you own.
- Across the top of the BIOS should be a few different options, we need to get to the **Boot/Start Up** options menu. Normally is it to the right.
- Once in the **Boot** options, there should be another submenu called **Boot Order**. This is where you want to check if the device you are trying to boot from is enabled and where it sits in the boot order. Follow the onscreen instructions to move (normally +/-) the devices up/down. If the device you want is disabled, you will need to enable it (normally <kbd>x</kbd>, sometimes an <kbd>F key</kbd>).
- Once your preferred boot device is enabled/at the top you can save your changes (<kbd>F10</kbd>) and restart.
- After restarting, follow the below instructions.

To boot from a non-HDD device:

- As you start up the computer tap the <kbd>F12</kbd> key repeatedly until you see the Lenovo Boot Device Menu.
- From the Boot Device Menu you can choose to boot from your desired boot device.

Comment: thank you michael but still getting the same answer here. PXE-E61: Media test failure,check cable.                            PXE-MOF: Exiting PXE ROM.                              OS not found.

Comment: If you are getting PXE issues, then your computer is attempting to launch from a network controller.

Comment: ok, what do i do?? try something else for ex try booting from a flush drive?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please re-read it and let me know if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: i have tried this and nothing is happening. maybe theHDD is dead.

Comment: The HDD is independent from your ability to boot from different media. What do you mean when you say "Nothing is happening."

Comment: i mean i get the same message as before michael Os not found. probably damaged something when i nuked it